# Sub-domain as variable in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to mod-rewrite based on a sub-domain. How do I take the subdomain and append it to the end of my new domain?

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://www.example.com/?subdomain=[variable for sub]     [L]
```

How do I get 'users' into [variable for sub]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matches from the last `RewriteCond` are stored as %N so you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(users)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://www.example.com/?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: It's fine. But i have tones of conditions and rules that uses domain switching in .htaccess file. Those looks like .dev .stage .test envs. And making RewriteCond in above of each is quite harmfull. Could i have set one defined in condition at begin of request? Making R..R - [E=domain:%1] and after that - R..R redirectLink{ENV:domain} doesn't work. How should i get that later from variable in RewriteRule in right maner?

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer has only one subdomain (users) , i needed a WildCard rewrite rule (all subdomains) so i used the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?subdomain=%1&path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

or as reverse proxy :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.backendserver.com:3001/$1 [L,P,QSA]
```