# WordPress: Same content from either a subdomain or subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, subdomain

I apologize in advance for not having very many examples of effort already put into solving this. I've been googling and racking my brain but I can't even begin to visualize how this should be done.

We have a WordPress site with a Woocommerce store. To put it simply, we will be selling products for various resorts, and each resort will have their own product category to keep everything separate. So for instance if someone goes to `https://www.oursite.com/resort-1`, it'll be a page with all of Resort 1's products. This is all fine and good.

The problem: for each resort, we also have iPad kiosks that will use Kiosk Pro to display each resort's products and allow them to be purchased. These kiosk versions of the site must be accessible via a subdomain, e.g. `https://resort-1.oursite.com`. These subdomain versions should start with a landing page, then lead to the expected product listing but with a slightly different look (all via css).

My questions:

1. How can I set up a subdomain to lead to a specific page without using a multisite?
2. How can I adjust all links on each page so if someone starts on the kiosk subdomain, they'll stay on the kiosk version no matter where they navigate to?

Comment: Hello Keith. You could add for every Resort a Subdomain. It should look like this https://oursite.resort-1.com. This can be done with Subdomains.

Comment: But how would I change the links so people stay on the version of the site they started on? For instance if someone is on the kiosk/subdomain version (`resort-1.oursite.com`) and they click a product, it should lead to `resort-1.oursite.com/products/this-product`, instead of the regular non-subdomain version. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I think it's OK to offer a bounty in the comments, but bear in mind you cannot add that for two days anyway. However, please keep posts concise: a good guideline is that if something would not be useful to other readers in six months time, don't put it in.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that one way to accomplish this would be to:

a) use htaccess to route to a page with the subdomain passed as a var, for example subdomain.domain.com/page to domain.com/page?sd=subdomain

[Mod Rewrite Subdomain to PHP with GET variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330716/mod-rewrite-subdomain-to-php-with-get-variable)
[Sub-domain as variable in mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488983/sub-domain-as-variable-in-mod-rewrite)

and then;
b) include code in your theme if (sd = sudomain ) {do_something()} where do something uses a different style.css and modifies any html within the page as desired.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about skipping the subdomain altogether and just using a query string / session variable to keep track of the kiosk state. So we could set the homepage of the kiosk to `https://oursite.com/landing-page/?kiosk`, then in the PHP I can check for that `kiosk` query string and use it to create a session so any other pages they navigate to will also use the kiosk styling. What do you think about that?

Comment: I like it. The only real value of a subdomain here would seem to be that is allow the kiosks to post their subdomain for their customers. In any case, you could later accomplish this with the same htacess redirect method mentioned previously.